# Empty UIFont families on iOS 9 Beta 5

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I am trying iOS 9.0 Beta 5 build 13A4325c and found an interesting peculiarity: some font families do not have fonts inside.

I use the code:

```
  NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];

  for(NSString *familyName in familyNames)
  {
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];

    if(!fontNames.count)
    {
      NSLog(@"No fonts for family: %@", familyName);
    }
  }
```

The output is:

```
No fonts for family: Telugu Sangam MN
No fonts for family: Heiti SC
No fonts for family: Heiti TC
No fonts for family: Bangla Sangam MN
```

Why? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's likely a bug/oversight related to upcoming font changes, and you should [file a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Among the font changes in iOS 9/OS X 10.11, Ping Fang is the replacement for Heiti SC/TC.

From the [El Capitan Preview](https://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/):

> The new Chinese system font Ping Fang is designed for a modern appearance and crisp onscreen readability in both Traditional and Simplified Chinese.

It's possible that the Telugu Sangam and Bangla Sangam fonts were also replaced, although I cannot find any mention about which font replaced them.

I don't know whether the replaced fonts will remain bundled for backward compatibility, or get moved to the list of downloadable fonts for iOS 9.

Apple does provide [sample code for Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/DownloadFont/Introduction/Intro.html) on demand.

> Demonstrates how to download fonts on demand on iOS 6 and later.
>
> On iOS 6, we have added the capability for applications to download fonts on demand. Besides the fonts installed with iOS 6, applications can install a list of additional fonts as necessary.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The question is why a family would exist at all if it contains no fonts.

Comment: @matt Thanks for pointing that out.  Is the new first sentence sufficient improvement?

Comment: I guess... :) In my opinion, just saying it's probably a bug and probably harmless is sufficient. But that's up to you, obviously; I don't like people telling me what to say and I assume you don't either. :))))

Comment: @PetahChristian, plausible. Will mark as an answer.
Though this bug was not so harmless. I have discovered crashes at startup due to the legacy code, assuming that there is always at least one font in a family, picking the first and putting its name into NSDictionary.